# When I try to ping my VM's using ansible, it tries to ping the server id instead of IP

Tags: dynamic, ansible, openstack, inventory, heat

I created a VM using OpenStack heat and after creating VM, I tried to ping the VM using ansible using dynamic inventory `openstack_inventory.py` provided by Ansible.
But when I use ping module, it is trying to connect with VM's id instead of IP.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the variable "use_hostnames" in your openstack.yaml ?
Try toggling the variable value.

> **use_hostnames** changes the behavior from registering every host with
>   its UUID  and making a group of its hostname to only
>   doing this if the hostname in question has more than
>   one server

Reference: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/openstack_inventory.py

Comment: use_hostnames = inventory.extra_config['use_hostnames']

Comment: And Anant I also changed the following line.          
It was ansible_host=server['interface_ip'] and I changed it to ansible_host=server['private_v4']